# Redux machaca los estados previos

Tags: react-native, reactjs, redux

Tengo un registro en react native que tiene varios inputs, que recogen la información la validan y la envían al store global para luego mandarla a la bbdd.

El tema esta en que además de los inputs, tengo un datepicker y un dropdown que son dos componentes hijos dentro del registro.

He conectado el dropdown a redux con su action e incluido el el swtich 'user' del reducer, me recoge bien la información y la paso al componente padre mediante un props.

El problema es que cuando selecciono fecha con el datePicker sobre escribe el estado del dropdown y no puedo pasarlo como un prop al registro....

No se si es un problema de estructura mio, por que es el primer proyecto que hago con Redux.

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Completa tu pregunta con el código que estas probando y el error que te se te esta mostrando para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues no deberías de pasar nada con los props. Pues defines los state dependiendo el formulario. Entonces al llamar la action automáticamente se actualiza, luego con un effect guardas en BD